# Gentoo: Cannot add python_targets_python3_7 to pip emerge

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, target, gentoo

I am unable to add python_targets_python3_7 to my pip emerge.

I have added it to /etc/portage/package.use/dev-python

```
cat /etc/portage/package.use/dev-python 
dev-python/pip python_targets_python3_7 PYTHON_TARGETS: python3_7
```

In accordance with this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320313/python3-5-in-python-targets-not-working-in-gentoo I have also added the following to /etc/portage/profile/use.stable.mask

```
cat /etc/portage/use.stable.mask 
-python_targets_pyton3_7
-python_single_target_python3_7
```

Unfortunately this does not lead to the flag being used in the emerge

```
emerge -av dev-python/pip

 * IMPORTANT: 1 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.


These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] dev-python/pip-19.3.1-r1::gentoo  USE="-test -vanilla" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_6 (-pypy3) (-python3_7)" 0 KiB

Total: 1 package (1 new), Size of downloads: 0 KiB

Would you like to merge these packages? [Yes/No] N

Quitting.
```

According to https://packages.gentoo.org/useflags/python_targets_python3_7 pip is compatible with python 3.7.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This should go to the unix.stackexchange.com site, as neither the question nor the answer have anything to do with programming.  Questions pertaining to working with, configuring, or maintaining linux or unix-like systems should be asked there instead.  The link referenced in the question indicate as much.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was two part.

The issue is described in the emerge man page as the fourth symbol from the top:

```
Symbol  Location    Meaning

-   prefix  not enabled (either disabled or removed)
*   suffix  transition to or from the enabled state
%   suffix  newly added or removed
()  circumfix   forced, masked, or removed
{}  circumfix   state is bound to FEATURES settings
```

To remove this restriction you must use the solution found at https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1068102.html. I have updated the command below for python3_7.

```
echo "dev-python/pip -python_targets_python3_7" >> /etc/portage/profile/package.use.mask
```

Then to add the python target to the build:

```
echo "dev-python/pip python_targets_python3_7" >> /etc/portage/package.use/dev-python
```